# Как протестировать с Mockito множественный запрос с разными аргументами?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito

Есть тест. В метод прилетает список. На каждый элемент этого списка нужно вызвать метод. Как протестировать с помощью Mockito факт того что этот метод вызывается N-ое количество раз и понять что на каждой итерации прилетают именно нужные мне аргументы?

**P.S.** Дополню флоу.

У меня есть функция которая получает на вход N-ое количество карт и мне необходимо на каждую полученную карту сделать запись в аналитику. Собственно мне нужно проверить что метод вызывается N-ое количество раз и с нужными параметрами на каждой итерации.

```
verify(analytics, times(2)).write(any(), any())
```

Вот так я могу просто проверить множественный вызов. Но мне непонятно как проверить, что на каждом вызове нужные параметры.

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что вы хотите протестировать работу маппера, в репозитории. Подскажите, на каждый элемент списка вызывается один и тот же метод? И какой результат этот метод выдаёт, преобразует и складывает полученный элемент в новый список?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если порядок не важен:

```
verify(analytics, atLeastOnce()).write(p11, p12);
verify(analytics, atLeastOnce()).write(p21, p22);
```

Если порядок важен:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(analytics);
inOrder.verify(analytics).write(p11, p12);
inOrder.verify(analytics).write(p21, p22);
```

Естественно, это можно обернуть в цикл и пройтись по коллекции параметров.

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант рабочий.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ @Vitalii Viretenko оказался верным, но я нашел еще одно решение.

Мы можем использовать ArgumentCaptor для того чтоб перехватить результаты вызова методов и потом проверить их валидность.

Для единичного аргумента:

```
argumentCaptor<String>().apply {
            verify(mock, times(2)).someMethod(capture())
            assertThat(allValues).containsExactlyElementsOf(exceptedResult)
        }
```

Для пары аргументов:

```
argumentCaptor<String, String>().apply {
            verify(mock, times(2)).someMethod(first.capture(), second.capture())
            assertThat(first.allValues).containsExactlyElementsOf(exceptedResult1)
            assertThat(second.allValues).containsExactlyElementsOf(exceptedResult2)
        }
```

В целом если открыть класс com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.ArgumentCaptor там есть методы до 5 аргументов.